# G-parted, Need help expanding my home partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I want to increase the size of my home partition (ext 4 in picture), I know how to expand partition if there is a free space to the right of my partition. But the partition to the right of my ext4 partition is swap space and I don't know if I want to interefere with that. Is there anyway I can expand my ext 4 partition to get size from the partition left of it (/dev/sda5)?
[image: G-parted snapshot]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since `/dev/sda5` is a Windows partition, I would first use Windows tools to shrink it. Then use a Live USB/DVD of Ubuntu and Gparted to move `/dev/sda8` (ext4) to the left and then expand it.

Comment: Note that Windows NTFS partitions like 30% free. At 20% free they slow down  and at 10% you just about cannot do a defrag. Generally better to use Windows to resize NTFS partitions, and reboot immediately and run chkdsk on resized partition. Make sure fast start up or hibernation is off. Generally you do not have a lot of extra space, time to house clean or larger drive.

Comment: okay, after I shrink the NTFS partitions in Windows, how do I move the free space to the right of my ext4 partition?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a GParted LiveCD from [here](https://gparted.org/livecd.php). AFAIK you cannot change a partition that is currently mounted.

And about the resizing. You can always remove space from one partition and move it to the left or right side of the partition. That way you can move a free space from the very left to the very right.

Comment: How do I move a free space from left to right? It doesn't give me any such option.

Comment: Click Resize/Move and then click on the partition block with the arrows and drag it to one side.

Comment: Thanks, It works, I will try and get the gparted live and try. Thanks!